# Angular - Uniquely identify element within recursive ng-content

Tags: angular, transclusion

I have a custom component, called 'splitter', that's template includes an `ng-content` element, which should support itself as valid content.

splitter.component.html:

```
<div #container>

  <div>
    <ng-content select="[a]"></ng-content>
  </div>

  <div>
    <ng-content select="[b]"></ng-content>
  </div>

</div>
```

A template using the splitter:

```
<app-splitter>

  <app-splitter a>
  </app-splitter>

  <div b>
  </div>

</app-splitter>
```

When I attempt to get the height of a given splitter's 'container' div, in splitter.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;
...
console.log(this.container.nativeElement.offsetHeight)
```

it seems that I'm always getting a reference to the highest level 'container'. In other words, the same value is printed for every splitter instance, even though I've confirmed that the heights are different visually and in Chrome's developer tools.

Is there a way to identify the container unique to a given splitter?

Comment: `@ViewChild` queries the component's view. Not it's contents from `<ng-content>`. The reason you are likely seeing the same values is because the DOM hasn't finished updating.

Comment: @Reactgular The console.log(...) statement is in ngAfterViewInit() - is there a better way to wait until the DOM has finished updating?

Comment: There isn't an easier way, because if child component have structural directives like `*ngIf` you don't know when they will be modified. Especially if they use `async`. You can only make a guess. Try using `window.setTimeout()` to see if that helps, but it's not a perfect solution.